# Dynamically loading XML file to Linearlayout

Tags: android

I have 2 xml file like this:

**main.xml**:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**items.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_shop2" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/providerName"
    style="@style/WhiteTextMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Example" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

main.xml is used for MainActivity.
My question is how to dynamically load 3 layouts **items.xml** to Linearlayout in the `HorizontalScrollView` of **main.xml**!

Comment: Inflate your Items layout and add one by one to your HorizontalView...

Comment: Can you give me source code so far...!

Comment: @HT No i have not..I just give you an idea...Now do the search on Google ....you'll get code.....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
LinearLayout ll;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
   for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.items,null);
        ImageView imageView =  view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        TextView providerName =  view.findViewById(R.id.providerName);
        // Assigning value to  imageview and textview here
        ll.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you can you please upvote ans if it is useful to you ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for doing so:

Way to Left (using xml if the number of items is fixed) :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

          <include
             android:id="@+id/item1"
             layout="@layout/items.xml"/>

          <include
             android:id="@+id/item2"
             layout="@layout/items.xml"/>

          <include
             android:id="@+id/item3"
             layout="@layout/items.xml"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Way to Right (In Activity using layout Inflator, if the number of items is dynamic) :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, ll);

for (short i=0;i<3;i++)
    ll.addView(v);
```